# How do I automatically run a method on a dynamically generated textarea with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a plugin (https://github.com/jaz303/jquery-grab-bag/blob/master/javascripts/jquery.autogrow-textarea.js) that dynamically resizes textareas.

To use it I do

```
$('textarea').autogrow()
```

when the document is ready.

However, it doesn't work on dynamically generated textareas retrieved by ajax calls. How can I automatically autogrow() new textareas?

Comment: By dynamically generated, do you mean created or filled ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ajax success event function put once again the `$('textarea').autogrow()`
after you place the text from request into page.

Comment: This will re-run `autogrow()` on previously autogrowed textareas. The plugin does not seem to handle such situations.

Comment: so run it only for textareas in container div like: `$('.containerDiv textarea').autogrow()`

Comment: I did this `$('textarea').autogrow().addClass('autogrown');` and put this in my ajax success event: `$('textarea:not(.autogrown)').autogrow().addClass('autogrown');`

Comment: @Hobhouse brilliant, best possible solution. I'm glad I thought of it :P

Answer (score 1):

typically you most likely will be appending the dynamic `texareas` to some container, if that is true, just initialize the plugin to the container scope only:

```
$("textarea", container).autogrow();
```

assuming the container is the `DOM` element with the dynamic `textareas`

Comment: Note that you will need a separate container for every `textarea` you add using this method.

Comment: true, or if the elements are added to the DOM, just use the ref to each of them and execute the init of the plugin; perhaps if the code of the dynamic textareas is given we can be of more use