# jquery function not getting called on automatically generated html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing a strange issue. My concrete html looks like follows:

```
<div class="pages">
  <div class="dynamicPages"></div>
  <div class="staticPages">
    <div class="span4">
      <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
        <li>
          <textarea class="newcomment field span12"
            style="width: 350px; height: 20px; resize:none;  font-size: 60%"
            id="newcomment${page.id}"
            name="newcomment${page.id}"
            placeholder="Enter comment here...">
          </textarea>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Now sometimes i generate the same html like what is inside the div class span4 and add it to div class dynamic like follows:

```
  $(".dynamicPages").append(page_html);
```

this dynamic html i generate after i make a ajax call to the server.

I have the following jquery function when the user enters the enter key in the text area.

```
  $(".pages").on('keydown','.newcomment',function(event) {
    if(event.which == '13'){
      ... do some stuff
    }
  });
```

Everything works perfect now.

Now i wanted to the following plugin for my text area:

> https://github.com/jaz303/jquery-grab-bag/blob/master/javascripts/jquery.autogrow-textarea.js

So i changed the above jquery like shown below

```
 $('.pages .newcomment').autogrow().keypress(function(event){
   if(event.which == '13'){
     ...
   }
 });
```

and in my previous mentioned ajax call in the success event i do something again so autogrow attaches itself to the dynamically generated element as mentioned in this [How do I automatically run a method on a dynamically generated textarea with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165941/how-do-i-automatically-run-a-method-on-a-dynamically-generated-textarea-with-jqu)

```
$('.pages .newcomment').autogrow();
```

But now i see in case when i add dynamic html the jquery function is not getting called at all. When i reload the page i.e when the html is populated from server side attributes the jquery function is called properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.pages .newcomment').autogrow().keypress(function(event){
```

This line is equivalent to this:

```
$('.pages .newcomment').autogrow();
$('.pages .newcomment').keypress(function(event){
```

This won't work on dynamically-added elements, because they don't exist at the time of the bind. You do event delegation with `on` earlier in your code. You need to do it again, and abandon your attempt at chaining:

```
$('.pages .newcomment').autogrow();
$(".pages").on('keydown','.newcomment',function(event) {
```

Comment: if i do it again what i did earlier i end up in two request being getting triggered on pressing enter key. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480022/keypress-event-getting-triggered-twice

Comment: @SaurabhKumar You don't need to redo the `on` call each time, only on the first initialisation.

Comment: I understood your point but than I have two times the jquery function being called

Comment: @SaurabhKumar I really don't understand what your problem is. Could you set up a working example to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I mean to say if i specify seperately $('.pages .newcomment').autogrow(); than i get two triggers to my jquery function when i click enter in my textarea because the autogrow grow also have some kind of handling when a enter key is handled

Comment: @SaurabhKumar I'm not familiar with the plugin. I'm afraid I can't really offer any advice on it. Again, if you can provide a  working example, I'll do my best.

Comment: I found the problem. I made a silly mistake. The reason two triggers were happening because i saw there was another div with class new comment. After i changed the date everything works perfect. But i was nice to know that chaining will not work on dynamically created elements.

Answer (score -1):

Use `delegate()` instead of `on()`.

> **.delegate()**
>
> Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the
>   selector, *now or in the future*, based on a specific set of root
>   elements.

Comment: The `on` call is the correct part of the code. (And `delegate` uses `on` internally, FWIW.)

Comment: You are right, and I was wrong. Actually I'd never investigated the Event source code and clearly until today I misinterpreted the docs. Thanks for your clarification